# Disk Space almost full

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory

I am new to Linux and my laptop is dual-booted giving 50 GB of space to Ubuntu 22.04, the remaining are on Windows partitions.

After installing Ubuntu, as far as I remember I had around 40 GB of space left. I installed ROS2 afterwards, space decreased to 2GB, but it was showing that ROSfolder only takes around 10 GB of space.

After I deleted the ROS folder, I have only 14 GB space left as shown in an image below. Can someone tell me why it is happening and what can I do free up the space?

[image: disk space]

Comment: For future reference, please don't post text output as images, just copy-paste as text, surrounded by `{code}` brackets. To find out what's taking up space check it with a disk analyzer. I believe **baobab** comes with Ubuntu, if not it's installable. Here are some other tools: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-analyze-your-disk-usage-pattern-in-linux/

Answer (score 1):

Your ROS2 (whatever that is) installation probably installed a whole bunch of additional dependencies that it needs to do its work.
And those got installed in system folders and NOT in the ROS2 folder.
Then you just deleted the ROS2 folder (without going through the proper uninstall procedure) and without properly uninstalling the dependencies that are no longer needed.

Look up the proper uninstall procedure for ROS2 first and follow that. (It is possible you first need to **INSTALL** ROS2 again to reach the starting point for the uninstall procedure.)
After that has been done cleanup the no longer needed dependencies. This is easiest with the command line command `sudo apt-get autoremove`

This should get most of your diskspace back. Some will not be returned as it is very likely your Linux installation as grown a bit in the mean time for other reasons. That is perfectly normal.